# Is it possible to create a game library database column?

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy

The idea is to create a route which allows the logged in user to add something to their library, and also delete it if they would like to. It is essentially a game library, storing the users games. I was wondering if it's possible to create a database column as a list which you can just add the names of the games to the list, or if it requires a different solution? I guess this would work the same way as a favorites list for each user if my explanation was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for your case is to create a sql table Named as Library
with UserName and Games as columns.
To get list of all games of a perticular user you can use:

```
Select Games from Library where UserName={}
```

In order to delete a game of a perticular user you can use:

```
Delete from Library where UserName={} and Games={}
```

Or you want to use a no sql database then you can store all the games of a user
against his name like:
{ U_name: ["game1","game2", ....], U_name2: ....}

I prefer the first method for this case.
Here sql would solve this problem, better than nosql, since there would be lot of read and write operations.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did this and it works perfectly. Only struggle now is making it so a user can only add a game once, so essentially check if that game and user combo already exists

Comment: @Marius Use: Select count(*) from Library where UserName={} and Games={}. If the above query returns >=1 then it already exsists, else you can add new pair. Do accept the answer if it answers your main question, and upvote if you liked it :))

Comment: The Select Count line is not working, is there anything which needs to be imported?

Comment: @Marius no it should work. or use can use Select UserName from Library where UserName={} and Games={}. and check if the query result if empty or not.

Comment: The "Select" simply does not work, it comes up as an error. So does "count()"

Comment: @Marius what error?

Comment: It Just physically doesnt exist as something to write, meaning my program says it doesnt exist and wont launch

Comment: @Marius Its too little information for me to help you, may the table doesn't exists or some connection related issue I guess, do share your git hub repo for this project or we can connect via email chats, so drop your email. Also do accept this answer if it answers your original question, So that this question would be marked as answered.